# How can I make a ClickOnce installer uninstall a previous version installed via .msi?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, windows-installer, clickonce

I have made an application (in [Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008)). The installer for the first version was [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) based (that is, a deployment project). But for the second version of the application, I have decided that ClickOnce better suits my needs.

Can I make the installer the newer version (ClickOnce based) to uninstall the previous version (MSI based)? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mechanism for this provided. You may be able to do it with a FullTrust ClickOnce application, then run `msiexec /x <product guid>`, and also make sure to invoke it with a `runas` verb so that it prompts for UAC elevation. Something like...

```
var options = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        Verb = "runas", //Needed in Vista and Windows 7 for UAC
        Arguments = "/qn /x <your product guid>", //qn = quiet with no UI
        FileName = "msiexec"
    };
Process.Start(options);
```

Comment: Assuming the MSI was installed for the same user profile and/or All Users and the use has Admin privs.  Personally I can't imagine why you'd switch from MSI to ClickOnce but heh, guess that's just me.